# Does the $n$-sphere have a *surjective* rational parameterization $p \colon \mathbb{R}^k \to S^n$ for some $k \geq 1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, spheres, rational-functions, affine-varieties, riemann-sphere

For each $n \geq 1$, does the $n$-sphere
$$S^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : x^\top x = 1\}$$
have a *surjective* rational parameterization?  That is, does there exist some $k \geq 1$ and a surjective rational map $p \colon \mathbb{R}^k \to S^n$?

Thoughts:

- I believe it is crucial that I have specified the domain to be $\mathbb{R}^k$ (i.e., contractible), because otherwise you could just cover $S^n$ in patches and then take a parameterization which is surjective on each patch.
- My guess is that the answer is no for each $n \geq 1$, but I'm not sure how to prove it, even in the case $n=1$.

Comment: Does rational mean algebraic, not transcendental?

Comment: @userunknown: rational means a quotient of polynomials.

Comment: If you really mean rational as in a quotient of polynomials, the answer is pretty quick: let $k=n+1$ and consider the rational map defined away from $0\in\Bbb R^k$ by sending $$(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\mapsto (\frac{x_1}{\sum_i x_i^2},\cdots,\frac{x_k}{\sum_i x_i^2}).$$ Is that really what you're after?

Comment: @KReiser For my case that doesn't work because I'm requiring the rational map $p$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^k$ (this is  why I thought it is important that $\mathbb{R}^k$ is contractible).

Comment: Indeed, by rational I mean a quotient of polynomials.

Comment: @KReiser: that doesn't work but not for the reason ccriscitiello claims! You need to take square roots in the denominator to get a unit vector and then it's not rational.

Comment: @ccriscitiello: the closest thing I know to an answer to this question is the Cayley transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform); if you take the first column you get a rational map from $\mathbb{R}^{ {n \choose 2} }$ to $S^{n-1}$. It's not surjective for $n = 2$; I can't tell whether it's surjective or not in general.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I'm a bit worried since the Cayley transform in dimension $1$ is secretly including the infinity and sending the infinity to the point $1$ on the circle. If the infinity is not included, then the map is not surjective. It is clear that $S^n-\{P\}\cong \mathbb{R}^n$ by using projections.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Numbers}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\Numbers{C}}\newcommand{\Reals}{\Numbers{R}}$
tl; dr: *Yes*, there exist rational surjections $\Reals^{n} \to S^{n}$ for every positive integer $n$. (The construction below gives immersions/submersions if and only if $n = 1$. There also exist surjective rational submersions $\Reals^{2m+2} \to S^{2m+1}$, and "exceptional" submersions $\Reals^{2n} \to S^{n}$ for $n = 2$, $4$, and $8$.)

---

As is surely known to OP and commenters, inverse stereographic projection is a rational diffeomorphism from a Cartesian space to a *punctured* sphere of the same dimension. A natural approach is therefore to seek a rational map from the sphere to itself that "covers the missing point."

For $n = 1$ such mappings exist, because the complex power functions are polynomial and map the unit circle to itself. Thus, for example, the composition
\begin{align*}
  t &\mapsto (x, y) := \frac{(2t, t^{2} - 1)}{t^{2} + 1} \\
  &\mapsto (x^{2} - y^{2}, 2xy)
  = \frac{(-t^{4} + 6t^{2} - 1, 4t(t^{2} - 1))}{(t^{2} + 1)^{2}}
\end{align*}
of inverse stereographic projection and squaring is a rational surjection from the line $\Reals$ to the unit circle $S^{1}$, among infinitely many others.

By taking Cartesian products, we get obvious rational surjections $\Reals^{n} \to (S^{1})^{n}$ of the real $n$-torus sitting in $\Reals^{2n}$. It suffices to show there is a polynomial mapping whose restriction to the $n$-torus is the unit $n$-sphere. For concreteness, let's consider the case $n = 2$, and write the $2$-torus as
$$
\{(u, v, x, y) : u^{2} + v^{2} = 1 = x^{2} + y^{2}\}.
$$
The polynomial mapping $(u, v, x, y) \mapsto (xu, xv, y)$ effects spherical coordinates, and is surjective because both $(u, v)$ and $(x, y)$ range over the whole unit circle. The usual iterative description of spherical coordinates extends this construction to arbitrary dimension.

---

There are noteworthy alternative rational surjections $\Reals^{k} \to S^{n}$ if

- $n = 2m + 1$ is odd and $k = n + 1 = 2(m + 1)$;
- $k = 2n$ and $n = 2$, $4$, or $8$.

Taking $n = 2m + 1$ and $k = n + 1$, we can use $\Reals^{n} = \Reals^{2m+1}$ as stereographic parametrization of the punctured sphere inside $\Reals^{2m+2} \simeq \Cpx^{m+1}$, use $\Reals$ as surjective parametrization of $S^{1}$ as above, and finally use the (polynomial) action of complex multiplication $\Cpx \times \Cpx^{m+1} \to \Cpx^{m+1}$ to get a surjection to the sphere $S^{n} = S^{2m+1}$.

Finally, there are three exceptional instances where the preceding ideas work: A rational surjection $\Reals^{4} \to S^{3}$ gives rise to a rational surjection to $S^{2}$ by the Hopf map. Similarly, the quaternionic Hopf map $S^{7} \to S^{4}$ gives a rational surjection $\Reals^{8} \to S^{4}$, and the octonionic Hopf map a rational surjection $\Reals^{16} \to S^{8}$.